# PayPal txn_id IPN check

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, paypal-ipn

Let me start by saying that, Yes! I did go through "Questions with similar titles" and couldn't find an answer to what my question is gonna be. I have a membership on my website, every time user purchases premium they get 1 month of membership (Stored in database as unix_timestamp) and the logic behind this is every time they purchase, it just adds this to timestamp

```
date("t") * 24 * 60 * 60
```

date("t") is the given number of days in a month.

I am using PayPal IPN and it wants me to check if txn_id exists. I've never used PP IPN before so I don't know what the roll of that is? Is it to prevent scammers? And lets say if it exists, does it mean that the user is trying to make same payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in case "lines get crossed" and you receive notification of the same payment twice.
- so you don't credit your user for 2 months, when she's actually only paid for one.

Ex. if your verification/confirmation of the first notification is too slow, they'll send it again
- appearing to you're system as a new one.. (except, it has the same txn_id)